# viewbinder row backgroundcolor

Tags: android, sqlite

how to add background color to entire row, not only on R.id.data column?

```
adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
      public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.data)
            {
            if(cursor.getPosition() % 2 == 0)
            {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY); 
            }
            else {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);  
            }

           return false;
      }
      return false;}
  });
```

Comment: get parent view and set its background

Answer (score 0):

With this code I set correctly background color to entire row!

```
{
((View) view.getParent().getParent()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("RED"));
}
```

but how to set text color to entire row?

```
((TextView) view.getParent().getParent()).setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

doesn't works!